# Where is Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I can't add `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox;` to my Windows Store Application. Visual Studio doesn't seem to know what I'm talking about. It tells me that it doesn't exist in the namespace.

Comment: What operating system are you running? Windows 8.1 is the minimum requirement to use `SearchBox` according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.searchbox.aspx

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1. Apparently `using Windows.ApplicationModel.Search;` API contains the same `SearchPane` class I was needing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A namespace is a collection of classes, to use one of the classes you need to reference the respective namespace.

`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` is **namespace**

`SearchBox` is a **class**

You need to add reference of `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
```

and create an object of `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox`:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox sbox = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox();
this.Controls.Add(sbox); //this line will add it to your app page controls list
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227716) is the list of controls available in `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` namespace.